# Pulled a repository using hg clone, but when using hg log can't see revisions

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

I download my code repository from:

hg clone https://sergiotapia@bitbucket.org/sergiotapia/sharpdic

And now I have the folders on my machine; I can open the solution and develop on it. Now when I run hg log I don't see the initial push I made. Shouldn't I be able to see the initial push on the log?

I though cloning a repo got the complete changesets?

Thanks for the help.
[image]

Comment: I just cloned that repo and ran `hg log` and I see a single changeset - did you make some change since posting this question?

Comment: I see that you did hg init prior to hg clone; I'm not sure that's necessary, and I don't know what the result would be.  If your initial hg init prevented hg clone from writing the log in your directory, that could be the problem.

Comment: Oh so I SHOULDN'T do a hg init? I thought I had to have a repo to sort of catch the repo that's being sent to me. :P Let me try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have created a repository (`hg init`) and then cloned an external repository into it.

You simply need to skip the first step and then `cd sharpdic` after cloning for your commands to be executed in/on the right repository.